# Python Pandas 0.13: normalizing dates and selecting times from dataframe with certain attributes

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas

I'm using the Pandas library that came with Anaconda, using python 2.7.9.

My question is two-fold.

I have several data sets that have a date and time field, however unfortunately the instrument that created them did not consistently label dates, such that all of them are in DD/MM/YYYY format, but the instrument seemingly randomly left off the leading zeroes of month and day for about half of the dates. Pandas has had trouble reading them correctly (from excel files), and since the dataset starts April 10th, it keeps starting at 2014-10-04, has unconverted dates in between (when the day goes above 12) and then starts reading them as YYYY-MM-DD again when that makes sense considering the input date. Is there a way to force Pandas to read these dates correctly, and concatenate the date and time fields and use that as an index, instead of it assigning numbers? I tried to create and insert a converter function for the Date field to format the dates correctly, but for some reason it applied *after* Pandas had already read the date incorrectly, and thus formatted incorrectly.

Since I want to index these data as a time series, what I was doing was simply creating a date/time range and then setting that as the index for the DataFrame, which worked fine. Except, for this data set, there are two days of data where the instrument apparently started taking data at a freq of a sample per minute, instead of a sample every 10 minutes. Is there a way to assign an index and force it to only keep matching records? Failing that, I've been attempting to try and query the DataFrame for only times where the minute ends with 0, or specifically delete those records, with no success at all. I really have no idea what to do here.

[Here's a link to a csv with sample dates.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcmhoz6vlr2ecxk/dates.csv?dl=0)

Among other things, I've tried:

```
In[168]: ddata = ddata[str(ddata[' Time'])[:5].endswith('0')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-156-098b3e02871f>", line 1, in <module>
    ddata = ddata[str(ddata[' Time'])[:5].endswith('0')]
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1678, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1685, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1052, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2565, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1181, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "index.pyx", line 129, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3656)
  File "index.pyx", line 149, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3534)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 696, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:11911)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:11864)
KeyError: False
In[169]: ddata1 = ddata.query('Time[4] == 0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-166-48cd98cf78bd>", line 1, in <module>
    ddata1 = ddata.query('Time[4] == 0')
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1816, in query
    res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1868, in eval
    return _eval(expr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\eval.py", line 235, in eval
    ret = eng_inst.evaluate()
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\engines.py", line 69, in evaluate
    self.result_type, self.aligned_axes = _align(self.expr.terms)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\align.py", line 136, in _align
    typ, axes = _align_core(terms)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\align.py", line 54, in wrapper
    return _result_type_many(*term_values), None
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\common.py", line 17, in _result_type_many
    return np.result_type(*arrays_and_dtypes)
TypeError: data type not understood
In[170]: ddata1 = ddata.query('str(Time)[4] == 0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-167-452d91f45daf>", line 1, in <module>
    ddata1 = ddata.query('str(Time)[4] == 0')
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1816, in query
    res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1868, in eval
    return _eval(expr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\eval.py", line 230, in eval
    truediv=truediv)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 635, in __init__
    self.terms = self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 652, in parse
    return self._visitor.visit(self.expr)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 314, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 320, in visit_Module
    return self.visit(expr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 314, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 323, in visit_Expr
    return self.visit(node.value, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 314, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 560, in visit_Compare
    return self.visit(binop)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 314, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 404, in visit_BinOp
    op, op_class, left, right = self._possibly_transform_eq_ne(node)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 355, in _possibly_transform_eq_ne
    left = self.visit(node.left, side='left')
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 314, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 440, in visit_Subscript
    value = self.visit(node.value)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 314, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expr.py", line 205, in f
    "implemented".format(node_name))
NotImplementedError: 'Call' nodes are not implemented
```

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of the csv containing the problematic dates that you're trying to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on the csv you linked to and it seems to work for me:

```
df.Date = pd.datetools.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.Date.head()
Out[972]: 
0   2014-05-31
1   2014-05-31
2   2014-05-31
3   2014-05-31
4   2014-05-31
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

For the second part of your question, you could slice your dataframe like this:

```
df[df.Time.map(lambda x: x.minute % 10 == 0)]
```

Comment: That totally worked. Thanks, this is my first project with pandas and I'm still trying to learn, I guess I missed that in the datetime documentation. Any chance you can give me a hand with the issue of the excess times as well? Edit: I should note that this issue is also displayed in the csv file, further down around June 3rd.

Comment: No probs I've added  something for you to try to the answer.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. That did it perfectly. I know what lambda functions are, but how does that one work, exactly?

Comment: `x.minute` is the minute attribute of the datetime object, and `%` is the modulus operation in Python, it means "divide by this number and return the remainder", if it's 0 then it means that x.minute is evenly divisible by 10.